# Input error using autoplot and ggplot2: Invalid input: date_trans works with objects of class Date only

Tags: r, ggplot2, quantmod

```
    library(quantmod)
GDP.growth <- ts(data = getSymbols('A191RL1Q225SBEA', src = 'FRED', auto.assign = F), frequency = 4, start = c(1947,2))

library(ggplot2)
library(forecast)

fit.1 <- arima(ts(GDP.growth[1:259], frequency = 4, start = c(1947,2)), order = c(1,0,0))
summary(fit.1)

fit.2 <- arima(ts(GDP.growth[1:259], frequency = 4, start = c(1947,2)), order = c(3,0,2))
summary(fit.2)

fc.1 <- forecast(ts(GDP.growth[1:259], frequency = 4, start = c(1947,2)), h = 20, model = fit.1)

fc.2 <- forecast (ts(GDP.growth[1:259], frequency = 4, start = c(1947,2)), h = 20, model = fit.2)

autoplot(GDP.growth)+autolayer(fitted(fc.1), color="blue")+autolayer(fc.1, color=alpha("pink", 1/3))

autoplot(GDP.growth)+autolayer(fitted(fc.2), color="blue")+autolayer(fc.2, color=alpha("pink", 1/3))
```

I get the following message:

```
Invalid input: date_trans works with objects of class Date only
```

When I plot only the autoplot it works. It seems the problem lies after the "+". Can anyone help me with this problem?

Comment: Error is clear, input must be class of date.

Comment: I cannot reproduce your error. The code is working fine for me. Can you edit your question by copy and pasting the output of `sessioninfo::session_info()`. Maybe it is the problem with your version of the packages (`forecast`, `ggplot2`).

Comment: Can you please close the R and reopen and load the required packages only `quantmod, forecast, ggplot2`? You have loaded many packages. So, there may be some conflicts.